# Regex to find and replace digits

Tags: ios, regex, swift4

I am new to regular expressions and need to perform a specific task with the same. I would require a regex that performs global search and checks if there are 3 or more consecutive digits in a string and if yes, then replaces all the digits with "xxxx".

For example, the string

> abcdef 12 quews 4567

should be changed to

> abcdef XX quews XXXX

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you said: `there are 3 or more consecutive numbers in a string and if yes then replaces all the numbers with "xxxx"` then why is `12` replaced by `XX`? 
Each number should be replaced by a single `X` right not by `XXXX`?

Comment: Like I have mentioned, if 3 consecutive numbers are found in a string then all the numbers in the string need to be replaced.

Comment: you need to replace any digit by an X? that is what you need?

Comment: yes, edited the question.

Comment: just check if you have at least 1 match with regex `\d{3}` on your input string, if this the case then you can just do a `replaceAll('\d','X')`

Comment: `\d{3}` will match exact 3 chars not more than that.....for more than 3 chars use `\d{3,}`.

Comment: @ShivakumarGouda Plz accept the answer if it works for you, it may help others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers, with all your inputs I was able to solve this with following code

```
extension String {

    func replaceDigits() -> String {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d{3,}", options: [])
            let matches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count))
            if matches > 0 {
                return replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d", with: "X", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
            }
        } catch {
            return self
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATED

**Use this**

```
func testingRegex6(text:String) ->String{
    do{
        var finalText = text
        let componentNSString = NSString.init(string:text)
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+", options:[.dotMatchesLineSeparators])
        let matches = regex.matches(in: text ,options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, componentNSString.length)).reversed()
        if(matches.filter({$0.range.length >= 3}).count > 0) { //here we check if we have any substring containing 3 o more digits
            for result3 in matches {
                finalText = finalText.replacingOccurrences(of: componentNSString.substring(with: result3.range), with: Array(repeating: "X", count: result3.range.length).joined())
            }
        }
        return finalText
    }
    catch{
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}
```

> **Input** "abcdef 12 quews 4567" **Log** "abcdef XX quews XXXX"
>
> **Input** "abcdef 12 que82ws 45" **Log** "abcdef 12 que82ws 45"

Comment: @ShivakumarGouda did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
let testString = "abcdef 12 quews 4567"
let output = testString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\[\\]^[0-9]]", with: "X", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

print(output)
```

Your output looks like this,

```
abcdef XX quews XXXX
```

**Update**

Find String extension class,

```
extension String {
    func matches(for regex: String) -> [String] {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
            let results = regex.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self))
            return results.map {
                String(self[Range($0.range, in: self)!])
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

and find below code,

```
let temp = "abc44def 12 quews 4564 1254"
let array = temp.matches(for: "\\d{3,}")
var output = temp

for val in array.enumerated() {
   var string = ""
   for _ in 0..<val.element.count {
      string+="X"
   }
   output = output.replacingOccurrences(of: val.element, with: string)
}
print(output)
```

you will get output like this,

```
abc44def 12 quews XXXX XXXX
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. This answers one part of my question of replacing digits with X. However, I also want the regex to do this only if it finds 3 or more consecutive digits in the string.

Comment: @ShivakumarGouda Consecutive means 456,567,678 etc, like this?

Comment: Any random digits appearing consecutively like 739

Comment: For Example, **Syf-33 fight 2378** should become **Syf-XX fight XXXX**, whereas, **MM 44 DDG KL6 FF 88** should remain **MM 44 DDG KL6 FF 88**

Comment: @ShivakumarGouda if in your string you have a substring with 3 consecutive numbers then you need to replace all numbers by X is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

With Reg. expression

```
let txt = "abc 12 wqer 987asd asdf1233sadf"
do {
    let regx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)

    let result = regx.stringByReplacingMatches(in: txt, options: .withTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, txt.count), withTemplate: "X")

    print(result)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Without reg. expression

```
let txt = "abc 12 wqer 987asd asdf1233sadf"

let replacedStr = String(txt.map {

  let c = String($0)
  if let digit = Int(c), digit >= 0, digit <= 9 {
      return "X"
  } else {
      return $0
  }
})
print(replacedStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "this is 123 my vie22w"
```

Convert string into string array

```
let characters = Array(str)
```

Use loop with counter and replace string if digits are more than 3.

```
var count = 0
for i in characters {

     if i >= "0" && i <= "9" {
         count += 1
      }
}
if count > 3 {

 let output = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\[\\]^[0-9]]", with: "X", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
        print(output)
}
```

Comment: is it possible to check the consecutive digits count in the regex itself?

Comment: No, as per i know not possible because it will not return consecutive digits count from string.